# bouncing balls animation Accordion

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, gsap

I am trying to make the animation shown in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/hamza-aabila/pen/WNbYjjv)

In the crown I have 5 balls. On the other side I have 5 balls in the accordion. Whenever I open a specific section in the accordion the ball attached to this latter move to same place in the crown. Thank you for your help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.acc__title').click(function(j) {
    let elem = $(this).find("i");
    let dot = '#' + $(this).data("dot");

    elem = $(elem[0]);
    dot = $(dot);

    let thisClass = $(this);
    let dropDown = $(this).closest('.acc__card').find('.acc__panel');
    $(this).closest('.acc').find('.acc__panel').not(dropDown).slideUp();

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      let dist_top = dot.offset().top - elem.offset().top;
      let dist_left = dot.offset().left - elem.offset().left;
      elem.animate({
        "left": dist_left + "px",
        "top": dist_top + "px"
      }, 500, "linear");
      $(this).removeClass('active');

    } else {
      $(this).closest('.acc').find('.acc__title.active').removeClass('active');

      $('.acc__title i').animate({
        "left": "0"
      }, 500, "linear");
      let dist_top = dot.offset().top - elem.offset().top;
      let dist_left = dot.offset().left - elem.offset().left;
      elem.animate({
        "left": dist_left + "px",
        "top": dist_top + "px"
      }, 500, "linear");
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }

    dropDown.stop(false, true).slideToggle();
    j.preventDefault();
  });
});

function animCollapse(element) {
  let elem = $(element).find("i");
  let dot = '#' + $(element).data("dot");

  elem = $(elem[0]);
  dot = $(dot);
  //console.log(dot);

  let dist_top = dot.offset().top - elem.offset().top;
  let dist_left = dot.offset().left - elem.offset().left;
  // console.log("Y : " + dist_top, " X : " + dist_left);
  gsap.to(elem, {
    x: dist_left,
    y: dist_top,
    opacity: 1,
    duration: 1
  })
}
```

```css
#values-and-missions {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #DEE4EA;
  background-image: url(../images/bg-dots.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 50%;
  background-size: 50%;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

#values-and-missions .crown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#values-and-missions #accordion .card {
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #D0D9E2;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

#values-and-missions #accordion .card:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D9E2;
}

#values-and-missions #accordion .card-header {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #e4e9ee;
}

#values-and-missions #accordion .card-title a {
  display: block;
  padding: 23px 15px;
  /* padding-left: 30px; */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #0F89CF;
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.05); */
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

#values-and-missions #accordion .card-title a.collapsed {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #dee4ea;
}

#values-and-missions #accordion .card-title a i {
  font-size: 9.71px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#values-and-missions #accordion .card-title a:after,
#values-and-missions #accordion .card-title a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #0F89CF;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: 15px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

#values-and-missions #accordion .card-title a.collapsed:after {
  color: #0F89CF;
  transform: rotate(0);
}

#values-and-missions #accordion .card-body {
  padding: 0px 15px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #615f5f;
  line-height: 27px;
}

#values-and-missions #accordion .collapse.show {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: visible;
}


/* Accordion
================================================== */

.acc {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.acc__card {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.acc__title {
  background: #fff;
  color: #212121;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.acc__title span {
  position: relative;
}

.acc__title span i {
  font-size: 9.71px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.acc__title::after {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid #4a6e78;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4a6e78;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  content: " ";
  top: 17px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.acc__title.active::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.acc__panel {
  background: #fff;
  color: #212121;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="values-and-missions" class="section">
  <!-- <img src="images/damandis.svg" class="crown" alt=""> -->
  <div class="crown">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="52.701" height="98.174" viewBox="0 0 52.701 98.174">
        <g id="damandis" transform="translate(369.132 -50.394) rotate(90)">
          <path id="crown"
            d="M111.133,357.154a116.647,116.647,0,0,1-8.392-19,116.684,116.684,0,0,1-8.392,19c-5.944,10.257-16.143,16.143-33.51-3.788l11.947,22.262H132.7l11.946-22.262C127.276,373.3,117.077,367.411,111.133,357.154Z"
            transform="translate(-3.123 -6.495)" fill="#0f89cf" />
          <circle id="dot_05" data-name="dot 05" cx="4.855" cy="4.855" r="4.855" transform="translate(138.858 335.942)"
            fill="#0f89cf" />
          <circle id="dot_04" data-name="dot 04" cx="4.855" cy="4.855" r="4.855" transform="translate(115.432 335.942)"
            fill="#0f89cf" />
          <circle id="dot_03" data-name="dot 03" cx="4.855" cy="4.855" r="4.855"
            transform="translate(92.751 323.297) rotate(-45)" fill="#0f89cf" />
          <circle id="dot_02" data-name="dot 02" cx="4.855" cy="4.855" r="4.855" transform="translate(73.82 335.942)"
            fill="#0f89cf" />
          <circle id="dot_01" data-name="dot 01" cx="4.855" cy="4.855" r="4.855" transform="translate(50.394 335.941)"
            fill="#0f89cf" />
        </g>
      </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="acc">
          <div class="acc__card">
            <div class="acc__title" data-dot="dot_01"><span><i class="fas fa-circle"></i> Accordion Title #1</span></div>
            <div class="acc__panel">
              I am the content found under accordion #1. You can't see me while "active" is not present.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="acc__card">
            <div class="acc__title" data-dot="dot_02"><span><i class="fas fa-circle"></i> Accordion Title #2</span></div>
            <div class="acc__panel">
              I am the content found under accordion #2. You can't see me while "active" is not present.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="acc__card">
            <div class="acc__title" data-dot="dot_03"><span><i class="fas fa-circle"></i> Accordion Title #3</span></div>
            <div class="acc__panel">
              I am the content found under accordion #3. You can't see me while "active" is not present.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="acc__card">
            <div class="acc__title" data-dot="dot_04"><span><i class="fas fa-circle"></i> Accordion Title #4</span></div>
            <div class="acc__panel">
              I am the content found under accordion #4. You can't see me while "active" is not present.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="acc__card">
            <div class="acc__title" data-dot="dot_05"><span><i class="fas fa-circle"></i> Accordion Title #5</span></div>
            <div class="acc__panel">
              I am the content found under accordion #5. You can't see me while "active" is not present.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use jQuery's `.animate()`. It's not performant and doesn't have nearly as much functionality as GSAP's animation capabilities. Same thing with `.slideUp` - you can replace it with a GSAP tween. If you're going to use GSAP's animation capabilities then there's no point in loading GSAP.

The steps you need to do are:

1. Set the position of the crown in its final position (i.e. after the section is open).
2. Get the x and y distance of the dot to its corresponding dot in the crown.
3. Animate from the *original* position to the final position for both the crown and the dot you're animating.
4. When it's closed, animate the dot back to 0,0 (you don't have to do any calculations).

It's also better to use GSAP's `x` and `y` properties because they make use of transforms which don't cause reflows.

I got you started in [this demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/PowxRmz?editors=0010). I did not do step 2 and 3, I'll leave that for you to figure out. Hint: make use of GSAP's `.set()` and `.from()` methods.